# Правильная статическая линковка

Tags: c++, c, компоновщик

Задался вопросом как же правильно строить библиотеки для статической линковки. Вопрос возник после просмотра содержимого результирующего исполняемого файла. Дело в том, что после линковки некоторых библиотек в исполняемый файл попадает много незадействованного кода. Эксперимент оформил шелл-скриптом для `*nix`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ `whoami` = "root" ]; then
   echo "Под учеткой рута работать отказываюсь."
   exit
fi

# если clang не установлен - нужно заменить на gcc и g++ соответственно

CC="clang -Wall -pedantic -O3 -c"
CXX="clang++ -Wall -pedantic -O3 -c"
LINK1="clang -static -O3"
LINK2="clang++ -static -O3"

# генерация библиотеки 1 ==================================
#
# все функции включаются в одну единицу трансляции
#
# =========================================================

printf "#include <stdio.h>\n\n" > testo-1.c 
for i in $(seq 20)
do
  printf "void SomeFunc_$i() {\n" >> testo-1.c 
  printf "  printf(\"SomeFunc_$i\\\n\");\n" >> testo-1.c 
  printf "}\n\n" >> testo-1.c 
done
$CC testo-1.c
$CC -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -o testo-1f.o testo-1.c
ar rcs libtesto-1.a testo-1.o
ar rcs libtesto-1f.a testo-1f.o
rm -f *.c *.o

# генерация библиотеки 2 ==================================
#
# каждая функция включается в отдельную единицу трансляции
#
# =========================================================


for i in $(seq 20)
do
  printf "#include <stdio.h>\n\n" > testo-2-$i.c 
  printf "void SomeFunc_$i() {\n" >> testo-2-$i.c 
  printf "  printf(\"SomeFunc_$i\\\n\");\n" >> testo-2-$i.c 
  printf "}\n\n" >> testo-2-$i.c 
done
$CC testo-2-*.c
ar rcs libtesto-2.a `ls testo-2-*.o`
rm -f *.c *.o

# генерация библиотеки 3 ==================================
#
# создается класс, где реализация методов включается в одну
# единицу трансляции
#
# =========================================================

printf "#pragma once\n\n" > testo-3.h 
printf "class GodClass {\n" >> testo-3.h 
printf "  public:\n" >> testo-3.h 
for i in $(seq 20)
do
  printf "    void SomeMethod_$i();\n" >> testo-3.h 
done
printf "};\n" >> testo-3.h 

printf "#include <iostream>\n" > testo-3.cpp
printf "#include \"testo-3.h\"\n\n" >> testo-3.cpp
for i in $(seq 20)
do
  printf "void GodClass::SomeMethod_$i() {\n" >> testo-3.cpp
  printf "  std::cout << \"SomeMethod_$i\" << std::endl;\n" >> testo-3.cpp 
  printf "}\n\n" >> testo-3.cpp 
done
$CXX testo-3.cpp
$CXX -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -o testo-3f.o testo-3.cpp
ar rcs libtesto-3.a testo-3.o
ar rcs libtesto-3f.a testo-3f.o
rm -f *.cpp *.o

# генерация библиотеки 4 ==================================
#
# создается класс, где реализация методов разносится по
# разным единицам трансляции
#
# =========================================================

printf "#pragma once\n\n" > testo-4.h 
printf "class GodClass {\n" >> testo-4.h 
printf "  public:\n" >> testo-4.h 
for i in $(seq 20)
do
  printf "    void SomeMethod_$i();\n" >> testo-4.h 
done
printf "};\n" >> testo-4.h 

for i in $(seq 20)
do
  printf "#include <iostream>\n" > testo-4-$i.cpp
  printf "#include \"testo-4.h\"\n\n" >> testo-4-$i.cpp
  printf "void GodClass::SomeMethod_$i() {\n" >> testo-4-$i.cpp
  printf "  std::cout << \"SomeMethod_$i\" << std::endl;\n" >> testo-4-$i.cpp 
  printf "}\n\n" >> testo-4-$i.cpp 
done
$CXX testo-4-*.cpp
ar rcs libtesto-4.a `ls testo-4-*.o`
rm -f *.cpp *.o

# линкуем исполняемые файлы ===============================

printf "void SomeFunc_1();\n\n" > testo-1.c
printf "int main() {\n" >> testo-1.c
printf "  SomeFunc_1();\n" >> testo-1.c
printf "}\n" >> testo-1.c
cp testo-1.c testo-2.c
$LINK1 testo-1.c -L. -ltesto-1 -o testo-1
$LINK1 testo-1.c -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -L. -ltesto-1f -o testo-1f
$LINK1 testo-2.c -L. -ltesto-2 -o testo-2
printf "#include \"testo.h\"\n\n" > testo-3.cpp
printf "int main() {\n" >> testo-3.cpp
printf "  GodClass G;\n" >> testo-3.cpp
printf "  G.SomeMethod_1();\n" >> testo-3.cpp
printf "}\n" >> testo-3.cpp
cp testo-3.cpp testo-4.cpp
mv testo-3.h testo.h
$LINK2 testo-3.cpp -L. -ltesto-3 -o testo-3
$LINK2 testo-3.cpp -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -L. -ltesto-3f -o testo-3f
$LINK2 testo-4.cpp -L. -ltesto-4 -o testo-4
rm -f *.c* *.h

# анализируем что попало в исполняемые файлы ==============

clear
echo "Найдено функций в   1-м исполняемом файле: "`nm testo-1 | grep SomeFunc | wc -l`
echo "Найдено функций во  2-м исполняемом файле: "`nm testo-2 | grep SomeFunc | wc -l`
echo "Найдено методов в   3-м исполняемом файле: "`nm testo-3 | grep SomeMethod | wc -l`
echo "Найдено методов в   4-м исполняемом файле: "`nm testo-4 | grep SomeMethod | wc -l`
echo "Найдено функций в  1f-м исполняемом файле: "`nm testo-1f | grep SomeFunc | wc -l`
echo "Найдено методов в  3f-м исполняемом файле: "`nm testo-3f | grep SomeMethod | wc -l`
```

Результат работы скрипта таков:

```
Найдено функций в   1-м исполняемом файле: 20
Найдено функций во  2-м исполняемом файле: 1
Найдено методов в   3-м исполняемом файле: 20
Найдено методов в   4-м исполняемом файле: 1
Найдено функций в  1f-м исполняемом файле: 1
Найдено методов в  3f-м исполняемом файле: 1
```

Как видно, что если разносить функции и методы в разные единицы трансляции, и результат собирать в библиотеку - то "ненужное" при линковке в исполняемый модуль не попадает.

Соответственно пара вопросов:

1. Можно ли как-то линкер "упросить" не заносить ненужное в исполняемый файл не используя выше означенный подход?
2. На сколько применим выше означенный подход для С++ (касаемо удаления реализации неиспользуемых методов класса)?

В данной теме прошу не поднимать вопросы проектирования, вопрос именно по линковке.

Comment: Наблюдаемое вам поведение - это *классическое* и ожидаемое  поведение процесса линковки. Она всегда работала с точностью до отдельного объектного файла (или секции). Делить тут что-то по линии "правильная"/"неправильная" не стоит.

Comment: Меня не интересует "классика" или "историчность". Заинтересовало наличие неиспользуемого кода в результирующем исполняемом файле и способ его невключения. А не включать его  я считаю - правильным)

Comment: @Majestio, так и решение классическое. Так компилируется добрая половина программ (когда функция == секция). Всё произростает из древности этого процесса. Относительно недавно как раз смотрел презентацию на эту тему. Жаль, в букмарках не осталось. Попробую найти.

Comment: Ах, нашёл! Автор busybox'а делал, ага: http://elinux.org/images/2/2d/ELC2010-gc-sections_Denys_Vlasenko.pdf

Comment: 0andriy, спс, познавательно. Нет, ну я как бы не против отдельную функцию выносить в отдельную единицу компиляции, хотя и не всегда удобно. Но для С++ "классика жанра" - файл-заголовок и файл-реализации. И получается, что без специальных флагов от неиспользуемых методов класса не избавится. В своем "эксперименте" (тест4) я попробовал и методы разнести по отдельным единицам трансляции, и все получилось - но это какой-то костыль  (ИМХО)

Comment: Не *единицу компиляции*, а отдельную секцию для линковщика! Это же разные понятия.

Comment: В том то и дело, что указанные мною флаги разносят функции из одной единицы компиляции (или трансляции, вроде так принято говорить, не помню) в разные секции. Без флагов - все попадают в одну секцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В большей мере с проблемой разобрался, отвечаю сам себе - может кому еще пригодится.

В случае, когда в библиотеку включается набор функций/методов, скомпилированных в одну единицу трансляции, можно использовать т.н. "function-level linking".

**Для GCC/Clang это решается следующим образом:**

- Модуль(и) компилируем с флагами `-ffunction-sections` `-fdata-sections`
- Собираем в библиотеку
- Компилируем и линкуем результирующий исполняемый файл с флагами `-ffunction-sections` `-fdata-sections` `-Wl,--gc-sections`

Тестовый скрипт в вопросе изменил, действительно работает как должно.

**Для VC++ протестировать нет возможности, решается так же флагами:**

- Для компилятора `/Gy (Enable Function-Level Linking)`
- Для линкера `/OPT:REF`